# Retrieve all data from salary table and also calculate Gross Salary(Basic+HRA+DA+CA+Medical) using Stored procedure? in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created Procedure which calculates gross salary of all employees from salary table.When executing stored procedure using execute statement Error:"invalid SQL statement" occurs and when i am executing procedure using PLSQL block then Error":PLS-00905 Object HR.PROC_GROSSSALARY is invalid" occurs

-- Creating Stored procedure --

```
create or replace procedure proc_grosssalary
AS
begin
   select s.*,(Basic+HRA+DA+CA+Medical) Gross_Salary from salary s;
end;
```

-- Calling SP using EXECUTE --

```
execute proc_grosssalary;
```

-- Calling SP using PLSQL Block --

```
begin 
   proc_grosssalary;
end;
```

display all data in salary table with calculated Gross_Salary in the form of table structure

Comment: Hmm, it's just a single `SELECT`, why don't you use a view?

Comment: The error is because you're not selecting the result of the sql statement into a variable. However, what you've done so far doesn't make any sense. You're selecting the rows, but not doing anything with them. What do you really want to do with them? Store them somewhere? Store a sum of the results somewhere? Pass the results out to a different program?

Comment: it is possible but without creating SP. I wants to create SP which calculate Gross salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task completed:

```
create or replace procedure p1 
IS 
cursor c1 is select s.*,(Basic+HRA+CA+DA+Medical) Gross_Salary from salary s;
emp_rec c1%rowtype;
begin
  open c1;
  dbms_output.put_line('Emp_No   Basic   HRA       Gross_Salary');
  dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------------------');
loop
  fetch c1 into emp_rec;
  exit when c1%notfound;
  dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.employee_number||'        '||emp_rec.Basic||'    '||emp_rec.HRA||' '||'     '||emp_rec.Gross_Salary);
end loop;
close c1;
end;
```

-- Executing the procedure using PLSQL block --

```
begin 
  p1;
end;
```

Below is expected Final result:

```
----------------------------------------------                                                                    
Employee_number   Basic   HRA     Gross_salary                                                                        
----------------------------------------------
 1                25000   10000   36750                                     
 2                7000    2800    11650                                     
 3                10000   4000    15950
```

Comment: Can you help me in dbms_output statement for formatting so that the data will look in table format and also this logic need to be written in stored procedure

Comment: your answer, should be part of the question, and not a separate answer. Also I believe the answers mentioned already should be enough to help you solve your problem.

Comment: above code is my answer and i am trying to create stored procedure using cursor also fetching data from salary table and calculating the Gross salary for each employee this is my expectation

Comment: @SudiptaMondal check my question now

Answer (score 0):

your PL/SQL syntax is not correct

```
create or replace procedure proc_grosssalary (out gross_salary number)
AS
begin
   select (Basic+HRA+DA+CA+Medical) 
     into gross_salary
   from salary s;
end;
```

Comment: when executing same error occurs i had tried this code Error: "not a valid function or procedure name"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cursor so that you can loop on records in the table.

Here is what I did -

```
#create a table for sample data
create table tsalary0918(Basic number,HRA number,DA number,CA number,Medical number)

#inserting sample data
insert into tsalary0918 values (100,100,100,100,100)

#checking if data is inserted
select * from tsalary0918;

#query output
BASIC   HRA DA  CA  MEDICAL
100 100 100 100 100

#create a stored procedure
create or replace procedure testproc
AS
    cursor cur is select s.*,(Basic +HRA + DA +CA +Medical ) Gross_salary  from tsalary0918 s;
begin
    for records in cur
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('DA is ' || records.DA);
        dbms_output.put_line('Gross Salary is ' || records.Gross_salary);
    end loop;
end;
/

#execute the stored procedure
begin
testproc;
end;
/

#output of the above execution
dbms_output:
DA is 100
Gross Salary is 500
```

Check online - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1744281398fe62a6cb42250641947249

Comment: when executing same error occurs i had tried this code

Comment: @Bruno there was an additional `end`, Boneist fixed the errata.

Comment: Maybe is from ` , just try to change with ' on line 8

Comment: create or replace procedure proc_grosssalary
AS
    cursor salaries is 
    select s.*,(Basic+HRA+DA+CA+Medical) Gross_Salary from salary s
begin
   for records in salaries
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line('Gross Salary is '||records.gross_salary);
   end loop;
end;
 /
 end;
-- Executing SP using PLSQL --
begin 
  proc_grosssalary;
end;

Comment: I also wants all data of salary table with gross salary

Comment: I want all data with gross salary

Comment: you just need to add additional `dbms_output.put_line` codes, for each column you want in your output. I am sure, you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider the option of creating a View.

```
Create or replace view v_grosssalary  
as select s.*,(Basic+HRA+DA+CA+Medical) Gross_Salary 
from salary s;
```

and simply do `select * from v_grosssalary` to get the output.

With procedures, there's also a `PRINT` command(which works in SQL* Plus and SQL developer) using `CURSOR` bind variables

```
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR
create or replace procedure proc_grosssalary
AS

begin
    OPEN cursor :x for 
    select s.*,(Basic+HRA+DA+CA+Medical) Gross_Salary from salary s;
end;
 /

Print x -- This will display the required result.
```

Comment: @Bruno : Did you try it? Where did I mention it doesn't work in oracle11g?

Answer (score 0):

But.. What do you want to do? If you want calculate salary for every employee and you have your information in the same row, with a simple SQL you could have it, something like this:

```
Select id_emp, name_emp, surname_emp, (Basic+HRAs+DA+CA+Medical) as salary
 from salary;
```

And it would be more quick than have strange functions and procedures.. If you don't like it, create a view like these and you'll have a column with the salary calculated, more clean and less obscure

Comment: Yes but my requirement is to create a procedure with the same result.I can make view or write simple select query to get result . Please help me to write query in procedure or function to get same output